# Extracting data from XML returning a node removal error

Tags: javascript, xml, magic-mirror

I have an XML output for my API call that contains the following:

```
 <channel channel="194882" name="Main Power Main Panel">
 <kWh>0.319</kWh> 
 </channel>
```

And I am trying to create a table with the `name` and `kWh`.  So, I just need it to output, `Main Power Main Panel 0.319` in my table.

I am receiving an error that `Failed to execute "removeChild" on "Node": The node to be removed is not a child of this node.`  I think the issue is that I have a `name=` element and not `<name>...</name>` element type, but I'm not sure how to circumvent this.

My DOM function looks like the following:

```
   getDom: function(){
        var wrapper = document.createElement("div");
        if(!this.loaded) {
                wrapper.innerHTML = "Loading...";
                return wrapper;
        }
        if(this.xml !== null){
         var table = document.createElement("table");
         table.classList.add("xsmall", "table");
         var channels = this.xml.getElementsByTagName("channel");
         for(var i = 0; i < channels.length; i++){
           var row = document.createElement("tr");
           for(var n = 0; n < channels[i].children.length; n++){
                if(channels[i].children[n].tagName === "name" || channels[i].children[n].tagName === "kWh"){

                var element = document.createElement("td");
                element.classList.add(channels[i].children[n].tagName);
                if (channels[i].children[n].textContent != 0){
            element.innerHTML = channels[i].children[n].textContent;
            row.appendChild(element);
            table.appendChild(row);
            }      
        else {
            table.removeChild(row); }
        }


           }
         }
         wrapper.appendChild(table);
        } else {
                console.log("Returned no Data");
                wrapper.innerHTML = "NO DATA";
        }
        return wrapper;
   },
```

This is for the magic mirror project, for those familiar.  Thanks for looking and for your help!

Comment: `row` is undefined in the `else`. Not clear what you are trying to remove

Comment: My XML output contains more than I showed, and many contain 0 kWh.  I was trying to remove rows that contain 0, since they take up space, and keep just those that had a positive or negative value.